# Android Honeycomb - Help to create master-detail with fragments

Tags: android, tabs, android-3.0-honeycomb, master-detail, fragment

I created a Android application for Honeycomb (particularly 3.1) with three distinct tabs.
In the first tab I'm trying create a master/detail relation, with a list on left side and detail on rich side, like as GMail application.

I'm a begginer developer for Android and I need help how develop this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [HoneycombGallery](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/HoneycombGallery/index.html) will be helpful for you.
And for more details check [Honeycomb SDK example](http://leihwelt.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/honeycomb-sdk-example/)